# Which LINUX command to be used for 'cut and replace a column' task?

Tags: awk, execute-command, sort

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24184546/

This is the file. 
Here, I need to replace the 6th column with numbers from 1 to 158 respectively.

The output should be like,
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24184581/

How do I do it, using linux commands? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you want it to be replaced ?

Comment: I have added the sample output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you request is basically incrementing a counter whenever column 4 changes. The `awk` command below does exactly that.

```
$ awk '$4 != last{count++};{$6=count;last=$4};1' input.txt                                     
ATOM 1149 N MET B 1 56.923 131.264 45.113 1.00140.13 N
ATOM 1150 CA MET B 1 58.169 131.437 44.333 1.00140.13 C
ATOM 1151 C MET B 1 58.225 130.444 43.220 1.00140.13 C
ATOM 1152 O MET B 1 58.569 130.785 42.089 1.00140.13 O
ATOM 1153 CB MET B 1 59.401 131.239 45.231 1.00140.13 C
ATOM 1154 CG MET B 1 59.536 129.826 45.799 1.00140.13 C
ATOM 1155 SD MET B 1 58.315 129.397 47.077 1.00140.13 S
ATOM 1156 CE MET B 1 59.098 130.370 48.397 1.00140.13 C
ATOM 1157 N SER B 2 57.860 129.183 43.517 1.00 86.33 N
ATOM 1158 CA SER B 2 57.898 128.164 42.517 1.00 86.33 C
ATOM 1159 C SER B 2 56.887 128.522 41.486 1.00 86.33 C
ATOM 1160 O SER B 2 55.901 129.195 41.780 1.00 86.33 O
ATOM 1161 CB SER B 2 57.559 126.761 43.047 1.00 86.33 C
ATOM 1162 OG SER B 2 56.212 126.721 43.495 1.00 86.33 O
ATOM 1163 N ALA B 3 57.122 128.084 40.237 1.00 45.56 N
ATOM 1164 CA ALA B 3 56.217 128.412 39.183 1.00 45.56 C
ATOM 1165 C ALA B 3 55.730 127.143 38.568 1.00 45.56 C
ATOM 1166 O ALA B 3 56.393 126.109 38.624 1.00 45.56 O
ATOM 1167 CB ALA B 3 56.865 129.235 38.059 1.00 45.56 C
```

#### Theory of operation

Each awk command can be structured in this way:

```
awk '/Condition/ {code block to run on condition};'
```

If condition is missing, code block runs for any line, regardless of its contents. In this example, we check whether the `$4` field (column) has changed ( `$4 != last` , reads as field 4 not equals to the variable `last`  ). If condition is true (which will be each time it changes and on the first line, when last isn't set yet), we increment the `count` variable.

The next code block `{$6=count;last=$4}` will run regardless of what line we're on. We just assign contents of `count` variable to field 6, and record what we saw in field 4.  The `count` variable will come into existence once the script encounters first line of the text and will be created when command evaluates `$4 != last` part. `last`, on the other hand, will come to existence when code evaluates `{$6=count;last=$4}` part.

Finally `1` at the end is simply a trick to make condition to always evaluate to "true" and print. Just a shorthand instead of `{print}` block.

To save  the result to a file, use `>` shell operator to redirect output in shell. For example

```
awk '$4 != last{count++};{$6=count;last=$4};1' input.txt > output.txt
```